# Can a join table have a have_many relationship of its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, join

I have tried and failed to create a `has_many` association from a `has_many :through` join table e.g

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :parents, through: :relationships
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :children, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base             <------ Join table
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :relationship
end
```

The reason i'd like this is because a child can have many schedules however in a situation like a custody dispute or messy divorce I don't want parent 1 to see the schedule that parent 2 has given the child. A parent can of course have many children so I can't put the schedule with the Parent model.

The same parent can also have many schedules with the same child e.g one for this week and one for next week.

I have tried other strategies but this method would suit the data best so I'd like confirmation if it is impossible or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following should do:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :parents, through: :relationships
  has_many :schedules
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :children, through: :relationships
  has_many :schedules
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

**EDIT:**
The above relation is easy to handle because it will give you schedules directly like

```
child_object.schedules     # All schedules of child
parent_object.schedules    # All schedules of parent
```

You can further filter this results by defining scopes in `Schedule` model

Comment: Thanks Uandl, I've got this all working in my app now except have come across one problem. I have a nested form where I create a child, parent, relationship and schedule all in one. The `child` object builds both the `parent` and the `schedule`. Any ideas how I can then set `schedule.parent_id` to the same `parent` created by `child`?